# Is this a good explanation for a start/stop/retain relay circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

The control circuit is in series with the coil of the motor and the motor works when the start button on the control circuit is closed. The start button is in series with the pilot coil meaning when the start button is closed the current goes through the pilot coil so that the contact closes and the motor starts. When the start button is not pressed the motor stops. 
[image]

Comment: Nope. "When the start button is not pressed the motor stops." That means you have to hold the start button in all the time you want it to run. If that is how you think it works can you explain the STOP button and the contact of R1 below START?  Is this homework? If so we will guide you through the solution rather than give you a direct answer.

Comment: @Michael scott - Hi, We do not allow questions to be "vandalised", even by the person who asked the question. As a general principle, once you have asked a question and got an answer, it is public and stays that way. If you don't want the question to be publicly visible (which would be an abnormal request), you would need to make representations to a moderator, in the first instance. You can click "flag" below your question, select "in need of moderator intervention", and explain your request and justification for a moderator to review. Therefore I "rolled-back" your edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the start button is not pressed the motor stops.

That is not what I see.  In your drawing, when the start button is pressed, one of the R1 contacts closes in parallel with the switch.  This contact maintains relay coil current even when the Start button is released.  When the Start button is released, the motor continues to run.  The motor stops only when the Stop button is pressed, interrupting the R1 coil current.

Comment: thanks this helped me understand it better :)